# printing the multiple string values in a single line in c

Tags: c, printf

I am reading a data from a method which returns 4 string values

```
 printf(%s,%s,%s,%s \n",modValuex.A,modValuex.B,modValuex.C,modValuex.D)
```

it gives values like below but not in a single line like(12,-12,45 )

```
12
,-12
,45

1
,-23
119
```

how can i fix this/
I tried adding a \r and \t as well, same result.

Comment: I guess that the error is in the `scanf()` call a few lines before. Please make a [mre] (showing that).

Comment: You are not printing signed numbers (`%d`), you are printing strings (`%s`), and it seems your strings *already* contain the newlines, so there is nothing you can do in that `printf` line to prevent them from showing up. I.e., the error is elsewhere.

Comment: yes , sorry i am printing the strings , how can i align them in single line

Comment: There are two ways to fix the problem. The first way is within the scope you show. That way is hard to understand, complicated, time consuming, error prone, unreadable, unneeded. The second way is easy and clean. If you want the easy and clean way, please provide a [mre].

Comment: Obviously the function generating the 4 strings is not doing what you want. So post that function together with an explanation of that you want it to do

Comment: For debugging purposes change `%s,%s,%s,%s` to `<%s><%s><%s><%s>` and see what happens. Probably you have a `\n` at the end of your strings. Show how the strings `modValuex.A` etc. are generated.

Answer (score 0):

This `trimming` of strings is best avoided, as commmented.

In C one possibility here would be to replace the first `\n` with a `\0` in-place.

```
char* chop(char *s) {
    char *p = s;
    while (*p++)
        if (*p == '\n') {
            *p = '\0';
            break;
        }
    return s;
}
```

called like this:

```
char s1[] = "12\n";
char s2[] = "13\n133\n1333\n";
char s3[] = "14\n";
printf("%s,%s,%s", chop(s1), chop(s2), s3);
```

it prints `12,13,14` and a newline.

The characters of `s2` don't get printed. `strlen(s2)` is 2, but `sizeof s2` is 13.

But that *method* (from which you *read* the *data*) should be a help, not a source of complication. (In C you rather assign a return value of a function)

Answer (score 0):

`modValuex.A` and others contain a `'\n'`.

To print `modValuex.A` without a `'\n'` either remove it before printing or  stop printing before the `'\n'`.

---

If possible, simply lop off the `'\n'`:

```
modValuex.A[strcspn(modValuex.A, "\n")] = '\0';
```

If `modValuex.A` and friends unchangeable, to stop before the `'\n'`, use a *width* limit:

```
// printf(%s,%s,%s,%s n",modValuex.A,modValuex.B,modValuex.C,modValuex.D)
printf(%.*s,%.*s,%.*s,%.*s\n",
    (int) strcspn(modValuex.A, "\n"), modValuex.A,
    (int) strcspn(modValuex.B, "\n"), modValuex.B,
    (int) strcspn(modValuex.C, "\n"), modValuex.C,
    (int) strcspn(modValuex.D, "\n"), modValuex.D);
```

---

`size_t strcspn( const char *dest, const char *src )`
returns the number of initial bytes in a string that are not in a second string.